# Windows keyboard shortcut to answer connected android phone

Tags: android, windows-10, phone

I'm looking for an app (freeware, preferably) that will, while an android phone is connected to a Windows 10 PC via usb, allow me to answer incoming voice calls (via phone's speaker) using a keyboard shortcut.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations SE!  Great question.  Can you please add the price range you are willing to pay, or if you are looking for free software?  Thanks!